# Set Range in VBA using a named range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a chart that I want to re-position. The chart is called Chart 1.

BalanceCFWD is a named ranged("A63") on the spread sheet. The cells above will be deleted as I am producing a report. When I delete the cells the charts do not move along with the cells therefore I am trying to write this code. This is for other users.

If I step through the code I can use the .Top = chart1top.Top and that will re-position perfectly. My problem is that this only works when I step through the code. If I let it go without break points the code chart becomes wider and outside of the print range so I am trying to define the width and height.

The ChartWidth line I cannot write without a compiled "Expected List" or ).

There is more code that follows adjusting data labels and other charts.

Is there an easier approach?

```
Dim chart1top As Range
Dim chart1Left As Range
Dim chart1Width As Range
Dim chart1HeightStart As Range
Dim chart1HeightEnd As Range

       With Sheets("Overall Summary")
        Set chart1top = .Range("BalanceCFWD").Offset(1, 0)
        Set chart1Left = .Range("BalanceCFWD").Offset(1, 0) 'same as the range above
        Set chart1Width = .Range(("BalanceCFWD").Offset(1, 0) & ":" & ("BalanceCFWD").Offset(1, 5)
        Set chart1HeightEnd = .Range("BalanceCFWD").Offset(27, 5)
      End With

With ActiveChart.Parent
    .Top = chart1top.Top
    .Left = chart1Left.Left
    .Height = chart1HeightStart.Height
    .Width = chart1Width.Width
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're deleting rows in Excel, but the chart isn't moving around, it sounds to me like you simply need to change the cart properties.

This is the default settings:
[image]

Note under `Object positioning` that `Move and size with cells` is selected. I would venture to say that you have one of the other two radio buttons selected.

You can manually change this for one chart, or if it seems to be an ongoing issue, you can record a macro to give you the exact properties you need to set, then set `Move and size` in code *prior* to your row deletion code and it should move about as expected.

Comment: FreeMan. I have already got those settings defined. 

I have run the report again and I blocked out the following code. It is not positioning as I would expect. A mystery as only the .top and .left are the only lines I have managed to get working.